# WFMLRSVCApp.ear file not found

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g, installation

I am trying to install Oracle 11g in my laptop. Im downloading the setup files from here:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html
```

I have downloaded `win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip` and `win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip`.

I have put them in the same folder and started the setup file from the `1of2` folder. I go until certain steps and finally during installation i get **WFMLRSVCApp.ear** file not found popup.

I googled and i see some solutions where `1of2 and 2of2` file should be unzipped to same folder and then start setup. I did the same couple of times but still im getting the same error. Any anyone guess what is missing?

Comment: This error occurs because the Oracle installation comes in two separate files. The instructions indicate that these should be unzipped into the same folder. So when you decompress the zip files, copy the contents of database/stage/Components of 2of2 into the database/stage/Components of 1of2.
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH220386.html

Comment: After you extract and copy the second ZIP, can you just click "Retry" in the error dialog? Or must the installation be repeated?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

extract win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip into win64_11gR2_database_1of2 folder first.

Then extract win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip into win64_11gR2_database_2of2 folder.

copy all 4 files in database/ stage/ components folder in win64_11gR2_database_2of2 folder(unziped) & paste them (no replacement) in database/ stage/ components folder in win64_11gR2_database_1of2 (unziped).

Then run the setup again. I experienced in it. It works..

Comment: thanks! I have been struggling with it for quite a long time. It worked. +1. Cheers!!!

Comment: Bizarre. Just extracting both into the same directory didn't work for me, but separate directories, and then copying over the 4 subdirectories, did work.

Comment: Apparently unzipping part 2 in the zipped folder messed up for me and created this error. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 16):

What you have to do is copy what is inside components folder ( i think four files )  in win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip and paste it inside the win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip  components folder and re run the setup . it works

Answer (score 5):

If you are installing the `Oracle Identity Management 11gR2`, you might receive the `WFMLRSVCApp.ear` file missing during Installation error during the database installation.

**The way to resolve this error is:**

Make sure you downloaded two disk

- **win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip**
- **win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip**

**Steps:**

1. Right click the `win64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip` file and select
   **Extract Here**.

[image]

2. The software will extract in the folder named **database** as below,

[image]

3. You can see the following folders and files under **database\stage**, note the `Date modified`for **Components** folder.

[image]

4. Do the same for `win64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip` file and click extract here, the extracted file will be placed in the same **database** folder
5. Now check the `Date modified`

[image]

6. That's it, now you can start by clicking `setup.exe` under **database** folder.

Hope it helps to understand easily.!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it's an easy one to solve: Download WinMerge and use it to merge the 2 folders that come out of the zip file from Oracle. That will do it.

http://winmerge.org/

Answer (score 0):

**1) Normally extract** win64_11gR2_database_**1of2**.zip and win64_11gR2_database_**2of2**.zip

**2)** Copy directory

```
C:\Users\Fatality\Downloads\win64_11gR2_database_2of2\database\stage\Components (from extracted win64_11gR2_database_2of2 directory)
```

to

```
C:\Users\Fatality\Downloads\win64_11gR2_database_1of2\database\stage\Components (in extracted win64_11gR2_database_1of2 directory)
```